# how to call from main.class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have this code that i want to call from my main class :

```
public void Display()
{

    Form1 z = new Form1();

    z.listBox1.Items.Add("=============================Summary=============================\n\n");
    z.listBox1.Items.Add("1st: "+Num1+" 2nd #: "+Num2);
    z.listBox1.Items.Add("\n"+" 3rd #: "+Num3+" 4th #: "+Num4);
    z.listBox1.Items.Add("\n"+" 5th #: "+Num5);
    z.listBox1.Items.Add("\n" + "SUM: " + Sum + " DIFF: " + Sub + "\n" + " PROD: " + Multiply + " QOU: " + Divide);

    // result = ("=============================Summary=============================\n\n 1st #: " + Num1 + " 2nd #: " + Num2 + "\n 3rd #: " + Num3 + " 4th : " + Num4 + "\n 5th #: " + Num5 + "\n" + "SUM: " + Sum + " DIFF: " + Sub + "\n" + " PROD: " + Multiply + " QOU: " + Divide);

}
```

in my main class i tried doing this: and i also tried changing the modifiers to public so i can use the listbox from my sub class..

```
Class1 zz = new Class1();

zz.Display();
```

My problem is how do i call the `Display` from the sub class to my main class?? I'm just new to C# i'll really appreciate your help. :D

Comment: That looks like it would work. What happened? What didn't go as expected? Or what still isn't happening? i.e. can you be very explicit about the problem here?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll post my whole code. My problem here is after clicking the button it doesn't display my desire output to the listbox.

Comment: @JonSnow well, what is the "desire" output, and what output *did* it display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by "main class" you mean your Form1. What you are doing in `Display` is that you are creating a *new* (invisible) Form1 (note the `new` in `Form1 z = new Form1()`). Instead, you should pass the reference of your *currently visible* Form1 to the method:

```
public void Display(Form1 z)
{
    z.listBox1.Items.Add("=============================Summary=============================\n\n");
    // etc.
}
```

In your Form1 code:

```
Class1 zz = new Class1();
zz.Display(this);
```

Comment: thank you. this solve my problem.. and thank you for having a open mind for beginners..

Answer (score 0):

make sure your sub class is set to public.

```
public class Class1 {
    public void Display {

    }
}
```

then you can can call that class from your main class

```
public class Main {
    public void SomeMethod() {
         Class1 zz = new Class1();

         zz.Display();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the question that suggests type accessibility is the issue here